# CSV file to mulit-dimensional PHP array

Tags: php, csv

Im working with this data:

```
name,address_one,address_two,address_postcode
Bob,1 A Street,A town,AA11AA
Andy,92 Church St,Manchester,M20 3JN
Sarah,893 London Road,Enfield,EN3 9HB
Freda,67 Green Close,Newcastle,Nw5 2ED
```

It's a well formed .csv file. I need to be able to parse it and then convert it to a multi-dimensional PHP array in order to format it as XML.

Once successful my array might look like:

```
Array
(
['name']=> Bob
[0] => Array
    (
        [address] => Array
            (
                [one] => 1 A Street
                [two] => A town
                [postcode] => WC2 9GH

            )
    )
['name']=> Andy
[1] => Array
    (
        [address] => Array
            (
                [one] => 92 Chuch St
                [two] => Manchester
                [postcode] => M20 3JN

            )
    )
... omitted
)
```

I would then convert this to XML someting like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<name>Bob</name>
<address>
<one>1 A Street</one>
<two>A town</two>
<postcode>AA11AA</postcode>
</address> 
<name>Andy</name>
<address>
<one>92 Chuch St</one>
<two>Manchester</two>
<postcode>M20 3JN</postcode>
</address>
...omitted
</root>
```

I'm getting closer with this code:

```
public function parseFile($fileIn)
{

    if (($handle = fopen("$fileIn", "r")) !== FALSE) 
    {

        $header = NULL;
         while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE)
            {
                    if(!$header)
            {
                $header = $row;
                foreach($header as $k => $v)
                {                   
                    if($x = strpos("$v", '_'))
                    {
                        $child = substr("$v", $x+1);
                        array_push($header, $child);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                        $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
            }
            }   

        print_r($data);

            fclose($handle);
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Unable to open the file!');
    }
} // parseFile
```

but it appears my parameters are out of sync.

```
Warning:  array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements in
```

with

```
var_dump($header);
```

revealing:

```
Array
(
[0] => 
[1] => 
[2] => 
[3] => 
)
```

If I rewind a little with:

```
$header = NULL;
while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE)
{
if(!$header) $header = $row;
else $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
}   
print_r($data);
```

I get:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Bob
        [address_one] => 1 A Street
        [address_two] => A town
        [address_postcode] => AA11AA
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Andy
        [address_one] => 92 Church St
        [address_two] => Manchester
        [address_postcode] => M20 3JN
    )
```

Which is close but I need to be able to split the headings (on the string '_') of the .csv file into parent child nodes (thinking in terms of XML not array).

So for example, address_one would become

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
    [address] => Array
                (
                   [one] => 1 A Street
        )
)
)
```

where one is child of address. And likewise for all other headings from the csv file that have an underscore in them. Headings without underscores simply get mapped to values as normal.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you say "$header = $row;" where you later add extra data to the header (array_push($header, $child)).

This gives you an array that looks like this:

```
array(
    [0] => name
    [1] => address_one
    [2] => address_two
    [3] => address_postcode
    [4] => one
    [5] => two
    [6] => postcode
);
```

You should not set the default values before you filter out this data. So you could use a $tmpHeaders = array(); and then fill them based upon the data in your row.

Something like this:

```
$tmpHeaders = [];
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    if($x = strpos("$value", '_')) {
        $value = substr("$value", $x + 1);
    }

    array_push($tmpHeaders, $value);
}
$header = $tmpHeaders;
```

This way, your data array and your header array contain an equal amount of elements. Now you can filter out the name and separate the address fields into an array field.

Comment: I need it to be formatted like thus:`
    Array
    (
    ['name']=> Bob
    [0] => Array
        (
            [address] => Array
                (
                    [one] => 1 A Street
                    [two] => A town
                    [postcode] => WC2 9GH
                                               
                )
        )
    ... omitted
    )

`